# How to retrieve nested values from complicated data class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, I encountered the problem as follow. The structure of the data class is a bit complicated.

I need to write a function in data class `offerSystem` to build the whole `MyContent` class.

My question is I want to pass value of `language` in `Offer` and `title` in `OfferDescription` to `language` and `title` in `ContentItem` respectively, but I do not know how.

```
data class OfferSystem(
    val id: String,
    val offers: List<Offer>
)

data class Offer(
    val offerType: String,  
    val offerDescription: List<OfferDescription>,
    val language: Locale
)

data class OfferDescription(
    val title: String,
    val content: String
)
```

I want to set value for one of the variables(`contents`) in a data class `MyContent`. The `contents` itself is a list of `ContentItem`, which has several variables.

```
data class MyContent( // there are other val here 
    val contents: List<ContentItem>
)


data class ContentItem(
    val title: String,
    val language: Locale,
)
```

I tried

```
data class OfferSystem(
    val id: String,
    val offers: List<Offer>
){
  fun toMyContent(): MyContent {
    return MyContent(
           ...
           contents = listOf(ContentItem(title = ???, language = ???))
           ...
           )
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to extract `language` and `title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate on the nested collections in order to build your `ContentItem` values.

You can decompose the work by first writing how to build a list of `ContentItem` from a single offer (one item for each description):

```kotlin
fun Offer.toContentItems() = offerDescription.map { ContentItem(it.title, language) }
```

Then you can use [flatMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) to create a flat list of items out of something that would normally create a list of lists. In your case, you have a list of `Offer`s, and each of them can generate a list of `ContentItem`s:

```kotlin
data class OfferSystem(
    val id: String,
    val offers: List<Offer>
){
  fun toMyContent(): MyContent {
    return MyContent(
        contents = offers.flatMap { it.toContentItems() }
    )
  }
}
```

Note that this approach creates intermediate collections (unlike the sequence approach provided by @squirrel), so if you have many many items in your lists, you might want to go with a sequence isntead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why `offerDescription` is a list but you'll have to iterate one way or another, perhaps like this:

```
contents = sequence {
    offers.forEach { offer -> 
        offer.offerDescription.forEach -> { description ->
            yield(ContentItem(description.title, offer.language)
        }
    }
}.toList()
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you will need to add the another fields that won't be set in this conversion as null (adding String? = null for example)

After you can do:

```
var offers: MutableList<Offers>? = null
contents.forEach {

offers.add(Offer(
language = it.language,
offerDescription[0].title = it.title
))
}
```

So you will be able to add set the offers created to your OfferSystem class

```
var offerSystem = OfferSystem(offers = offers.toList())
```

Comment: mmh... this doesn't compile and doesn't answer the question. The goal is to build a `MyContent` instance out of `OfferSystem`.

Comment: The ideia is the same:

var contents = MutableList<Offers>? = null

offers.forEach {
contents.add(ContentItem(
title = it.offerDescription[0].title,
languange = it.language
))
}

MyContent(contents = contents.toList())

Comment: It still cannot work, you can't add elements to a null list, and actually the compiler should tell you that

Comment: var contents = mutableListOf<MyContent>()
        offers.forEach {
            contents.add(ContentItem( title = it.offerDescription[0].title, languange = it.language )) 
        }
        MyContent(contents = contents.toList())